# Regular Expression for a present & only digits

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate a number in PHP, specifically a DB ID passed in a slug but can't seem to get the regex right...

I can't use `is_numeric()` because it doesn't filter the numbers I need, same deal with `ctype_digit()`

```
// Values to Test
$tests = [42, '42', '42a', 'a42', '042', 1337, 0, '0', TRUE, FALSE, '1e4', 'not numeric', 9.1, '9.0', ''];

// RegEx
return !preg_match("/[^0-9]/", $val);
```

It's working mostly but I need to test for a value as well in the RegEx, `FALSE` and `''` are both coming back as valid...

I've tried `return !preg_match("/[^0-9]{1}/", $val);` to check for a valid length (not value) of 1 but I can't seem to get it right...

I've checked out the samples & comments from from http://davidwalsh.name/php-validatie-numeric-digits but can't get any of the sample code to work...

Does anyone know the RegEx for **present and only digits**?

Answer (score 6):

Why double-invert the logic. The easiest you can do is assert that the whole string is made up of digits (1 or more digits to be precise):

```
return preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $val);
```

or

```
return preg_match('/^\d+$/', $val);
```

Comment: Sweet, works perfectly! I tried something like that earlier but mine was: `return preg_match('/[^0-9]+$/', $val);` Thanks!!! Think I'm gonna have to bit the bullet and learn regular expressions once and for all!!!

Comment: @BillJobs please consider accepting the answer to show future visitors that (and how) your problem has been solved. Same goes for your older questions if they have been answered sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return !preg_match("^[0-9]+$",$val);
```

Comment: a) You need to remove the `!` otherwise you get the opposite of what the OP wants. b) You are missing delimiters in your string. c) If you add them, unfortunately, this is exactly my answer.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice, i don't have a machine to test it, just put the expresion in http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/

Comment: You can't meaningfully use a JavaScript regex tester for a PHP question. For this simple case it might not matter, but in general there are huge differences between the two regex engines.

Comment: yeah, i know. Like you said, this was one of that cases where there aren't huge differences. Anyway, i'll keep that in mind next time.